# Multiple INNER JOINS in SQL Server results in repeated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I need generated report of staff with account and subarea.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    empleado_cuenta.emp_id,
    cuenta.cue_id,
    cuenta.cue_nombre,
    empleado_cuenta.car_id,
    empleado_cuenta.sar_id
FROM empleado_cuenta
INNER JOIN cuenta
    ON empleado_cuenta.cue_id = cuenta.cue_id 
INNER JOIN subarea 
    ON cuenta.cue_id = subarea.cue_id
WHERE emp_id = 5938 AND car_id IN (147,5,6,7,41,14)
```

I obtain this result...

[image]

When I add `subarea.sar_nombre` in query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    empleado_cuenta.emp_id,
    cuenta.cue_id,
    cuenta.cue_nombre,
    empleado_cuenta.car_id,
    empleado_cuenta.sar_id,
    subarea.sar_nombre
FROM empleado_cuenta
INNER JOIN cuenta
    ON empleado_cuenta.cue_id = cuenta.cue_id 
INNER JOIN subarea ON cuenta.cue_id = subarea.cue_id
WHERE emp_id = 5938 AND car_id IN (147,5,6,7,41,14)
```

Then I get the result:

[image]

I just need to know the name corresponds with `sar_id`.

Comment: BTW, "Plz" is not a word.

Comment: You only need to know which empleado_cuenta.sar_id is associated with which subarea.sar_nombre?  Please specify which columns you need to return, or how you would expect this to look.

Comment: I expect to look only.. emp_id, cue_nombre and sar_id

Comment: I'm supposing one of your tables cuenta or subarea has emp_id which needs to be in the join. Otherwise, your subarea table has multiple names (sar_nombre) for the same sar_id. For example, 84 is associated with 8 different names (sar_nombre). Please verify your data.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` applies to the whole row,so when you add a column naturally you have more rows corresponding with the distinct values for the respective rows.It`s easy to see, your previous 2 rows were multiplied by the 8 distinct values in `sar_nombre`